# In R, how does one coerce a Matrix to a Data Frame?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I want to convert a simple Matrix to a Data Frame in R.

```
library(Matrix)

m <- Matrix(c(1:6), 2, 3)
rownames(m) <- c("row a", "row b")
colnames(m) <- c("col a", "col b", "col c")
df <- as.data.frame(m)
```

This results in an error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(m) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("dgeMatrix", package = "Matrix")" to a data.frame
```

Comment: is there a reason you are using `Matrix` library? Otherwise just use `m <- matrix(c(1:6), 2, 3)`

Comment: In this example I guess not. In the actual problem I'm trying to solve, I'm using that library to build a sparse matrix. But being new to R, I don't know if it makes a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a method for `as.matrix()` so you could do:

```
as.data.frame(as.matrix(m))
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain to me (an R beginner) the difference between using the big M Matrix vs. base matrix, and whether there are any side effects to using as.matrix()?

Comment: I mainly used `Matrix` for its handling of sparse matrices and I think that's the main case where people prefer `Matrix`. So for a large sparse `Matrix`, calling `as.matrix()` might drastically increase memory usage.

Comment: Yes, that's why I happen to be using it as well, in the actual problem I'm working with. It happens to be a sparse matrix that's very wide and large enough where I'm running into memory constraints. Do you know whether as.matrix() will result in an additional copy of the data? I imagine base matrix does not store a sparse matrix as efficiently...

Comment: @Seibar Turning your matrix (sparse or not) into a data frame will make it dense anyway, so calling `as.matrix` is moot. You might want to consider whether you _really_ need a data frame.

Comment: What Hong Ooi said... If you want a sparse matrix, you need to use `Matrix`.... I don't consider this an acceptable answer `class(matrix)` vs `class(dgeMatrix)`. I've a feeling that not being able to coerce a `Matrix` to a `data.frame` is a feature, not a flaw.